# Get Template::Plugin::Date to accept MySQL dates as well as datetimes

Tags: mysql, perl, datetime, date, template-toolkit

I'm using the date plugin for Template::Toolkit (Template::Plugin::Date), it works well with datetimes (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) pulled straight out of MySQL, but it will not work with dates (yyyy-mm-dd).

What's the simplest way to get date.format to accept dates (without modifying the sql query)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[% date.format(yourDateColumn _ ' 00:00:00', '%d %b %Y') %]
```

Comment: Can you update your answer, it looks like $Y should be %Y instead.